# Intelligencia url rewriting with jquery mobile

Tags: asp.net

My site is working correctly with Inteligencia url rewriting and jquery mobile on local,but when i run it on server it shows the error that The resource cannot be found.
HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
I developed my whole site with asp.net and jquery-mobile combination.